# Do I have to bother about closing Realm database in Objective-C and Swift?

Tags: java, objective-c, swift, realm

[Java documentation for `Realm` class](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/api/) has method `close`. It is written in method details: "It's important to always remember to close Realm instances when you're done with it in order not to leak memory, file descriptors or grow the size of Realm file out of measure."

Neither [Objective-C documentation for RLMRealm class](https://realm.io/docs/objc/latest/api/Classes/RLMRealm.html) nor [Swift documentation for Realm class](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm.html) show anything similar.

Do I have to bother about closing Realm database in Objective-C and Swift? Why are these differences between platforms?

Comment: I don't have a straight answer to your question, but I bet the difference comes from the how the app lifecycle are handled on different OSs.

Answer (score 7):

No you don't have to bother about closing the database.

If Realm doesn't provide a `close` method, the closing is handled by Realm itself. As you already mentioned, there are differences between different platforms/operation systems.

Answer (score 3):

The difference is due to the different memory management schemes. Objective-C and Swift are reference counted, while Java on Dalvik and ART uses a mark-and-sweep garbage collector. This means that in obj-c and swift, objects are deallocated as soon as the last reference to them is released (or when the autorelease pool is drained), while in Java objects may stick around arbitrarily long if the application is not under memory pressure. As a result, Java objects can't reliably piggyback on the automatic memory management to clean up non-memory resource, but Objective-c and Swift objects sometimes can.